# Concat_ws not working in insert statement in hive

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive, concat-ws

Using hive, I'm trying to concatenate columns from one table and insert them in another table using the query

```
insert into table temp_error 
select * from (Select 'temp_test','abcd','abcd','abcd',
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),concat_ws('|',sno,name,age)
from temp_test_string)c;
```

I get the required output till I use `Select *`. But as soon as I try to insert it into the table, it does not give concatenated output but gives the value of sno only instead of whole concatenated output.

Comment: can you provide the "desc temp_error;", "desc temp_test_string;"

Comment: and also a single row of what you get when you give "select *" and "insert into table"

Comment: maybe `'|'` is a delimiter in the `temp_error` table?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
I found why it was behaving that way. It's because while creating table I gave "separate fields by '|'". So what I was trying to insert as a string into the table, hive was interpreting it as different columns.